# Installing openssh-server after Rescue Disk boot

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, software-installation, rescue

I tried to help a friend with hard drive boot problems.

I first asked her to make a rescue disk (Ubuntu 12.04.3), and boot from it.
Then I asked her to open a console (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and use `sudo` to become root. All OK.

Then I told her to install `openssh-server` - so I can remotely login and look at the system - but that does not work: openssh-client (and some other applications) are reported as "not going to be installed".

But openssh-client is already installed: checking with `dpkg -l openssh-client` shows this to be the case.

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Please post the exact error messages, and also post `apt-cache policy` for the relevant packages, e.g. openssh-client.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I cannot see the terminal (for clear reasons :-) ), but I'll ask.

Comment: The output of `apt-cache policy` would explain why the "not going to be installed" message is shown.

Comment: Cannot edit my question, because of spam

Comment: openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1)
                  Recommends: xauth but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not going to be installed

Comment: @FaheemMitha ssh-import-id is already installed

Comment: "Cannot edit my question, because of spam". I don't understand what that means. Run `apt-cache policy` for all packages mentioned and post the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with `apt-get`, it knows about dependencies, but does not know how to upgrade a dependency. And since 12.04.3 was released, both `openssh-client` and `openssh-server` have been updated, but the first is already installed on the rescue DVD.

You can have your friend do a complete upgrade of all packages before installing `openssh-server`. What is much quicker is to do:

```
apt-get remove -y openssh-client
apt-get install -y openssh-client ubuntu-desktop openssh-server
```

(`ubuntu-desktop` is depending on openssh-client, so it gets removed with first command)

You should be able to do

```
apt-get install openssh-client
```

but I never got that to work, and removing first does.

Comment: I have her try right now. Why does apt-get not find matching openssh-server and not only latest version?